# Android Screenshot problem

Tags: android, opengl-es, screenshot

I have an image in the screen and I have used `onTouchListener` on the image so that the user can rotate and scale the image by finger touch. After completion of image modification by finger touch, the user have to proceed by a button click. After the button click, I want to take a screen-shot programetically so that I can save the modified image as Bitmap. How can I take the current screen-shot? Is OpenGL is the solution for this? If it is, how can I get the GL10 object `OnClickListener`.

Comment: OpenGL is not useful for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to do what you want:

First as you try, save a "screenshot" of the view. you can do that easily on each view in Android by using the drawingcache:

```
myView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap myScreenshot = myView.getDrawingCache();
```

The other solution, And I think it is the best one is to add to a transformation matrix each update you do with your finger on the image. Then, in the end, reapplying again to the source Bitmap. You will so get the best quality for the result.

Comment: We have already tried getDrawingCache(). getDrawingCache() is giving the original state of screen before the modification. So it is not working for us. For the second solution, can you give some code sample for that?